# Error in signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date()) while signing opensearch request in Nodejs Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm uploading document to AWS Openseach using AWS Lambda.

Here's my code, I'm first getting credentials from `AWS` using `EnvironmentCredentials` and then passing it to `AWS.Signers.V4().addAuthorization()` method

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');

const esDomain = {
  endpoint: 'https://search-ddbsearch-xxxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com',
  region: process.env.LAMBDA_REAGION,
  index: 'type',
  doctype: '_doc'
};

async function saveInOs(doc) {
  const endpoint =  new AWS.Endpoint(esDomain.endpoint);
  let req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

  req.method = 'POST';
  req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
  req.region = esDomain.region;
  req.body = doc;
  req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;

  const credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');

  let signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'es');
  signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());

  let send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
  send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
      let body = '';
      httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
        return {
          message: "Document saved"
        }
      });
  }, function(err) {
      return {
        message: err.message
      };
  });
}

module.exports ={
  saveInOs
}
```

And I'm getting the following error (in line 26)

```js
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received undefined
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
      at prepareSecretKey (node:internal/crypto/keys:580:11)
      at new Hmac (node:internal/crypto/hash:132:9)
      at Object.createHmac (node:crypto:162:10)
      at Object.hmac (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:428:30)
      at Object.getSigningKey (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4_credentials.js:62:8)
      at V4.signature (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:98:36)
      at V4.authorization (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:93:36)
      at V4.addAuthorization (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v4.js:35:12)
      at saveInOs (/var/task/saveInOs.js:26:10) {
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
  }
}
```

Anything I'm missing here?

I took reference from this repo: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[AWS.util.date.getDate()]` instead of new `Date()`.